# MySQL CSV importing error: Invalid column count

Tags: mysql, csv

I get an invalid column count error while trying to import from a `;` delimited CSV to MySQL via phpMyadmin. The error is possibly caused by the `;` signs in the HTML text such as `&eacute;`. What should I do?

Comment: Use a different delimiter (or set an escape character) in the script that created the CSV. Otherwise you'll end up spending far too long in your text editor or writing a Perl one-liner doing `s/(&\w+);/$1\\;/g`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The records contained `<pre>` texts in coding-related articles, so I had to remove [CR] and [LF] chars (they were interpreted as new lines => new record), plus I had to replace `;` in html entities with something else, so now column count matches and the import was successful. Converting back the replace text to `;` everything works now.